# Crystal Reports 7 CrossTab Suppress Column

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-7

I'm trying to modify a report created in Crystal Reports 7 (which I know almost nothing about). I want to use a CrossTab, as this seems to be the best way to accomplish what I want. I have a column with three possible values: A, B, C. The cross tab creates three columns. I want to suppress C. How can I do this?

Also, is there anyway to create rows based on one field (i.e. a PK value), but display another - like a description? For example, if a list of states have a PK value of 1-50, I want them ordered by PK, but I want to display the state name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you ask is possible;

**i suggest not to use cross tab**: cross tab is intended for an uknown number of rows and columns (varying on data) ad for summarizing (max value, sum of values) results on a grid.

you should, instead:

- Create a blank report
- Drop the fields from the `Field explrorer` into the `Details` Section (just A and B columns)
- Use `Report Sort Expert` to sort elements no the PK value

Comment: Sorry. I need to clarify. The three columns are all one column in the datasource with three different possibilities (A, B, C). The crosstab will automatically group them into three different columns. I only care about two of them. Is the cross tab the right tool for this job, or is there a better way?

Comment: ah, ok. You can use a "Selection Formula" to exlude the values that you don't need.